# Styling vectors based on external configuration using OpenLayers

Tags: openlayers-3

How would one go about styling vector features based on a configuration file loaded by an application? Using functions for selecting features based on a property to be styled is problematic as one is required to create functions at run time. Any suggestions on how this can be achieved would be appreciated.

Comment: I already accomplished something similar, I think.  I have style definitions in JSON and read them in a `StyleFactory` that interprets it and transform it into a style function.  I think you could do something similar. How does that sound ?

Comment: That is exactly what I need to do... can you share what you have done?

Comment: The code is part of a private project I worked on.  I can't share it 'as-is' but I can explain it.  The JSON consist of a list of rules.  A rule has 2 keys: filter and styles.  If the feature matches a rule filter OR if there's only one rule without any filter, then the styles are used to create the style function.  The rest is pretty straight forward.  Define every possibility you need to support and program it.  HTH.

Comment: I think I understand. When is the style function defined? When the vector layer is defined?

Comment: 1) create the factory    2) call `factory.createStyleFunction(rules)`  3) use the returned style function for your vector layer creation.

Comment: Okay. I think my issue is that I don't understand how to extend a function... adding multiple conditionals (e.g. if val= a, if val = b, etc...) based on rules provided. Based on what you have provided I can get it to work now for one rule, but somehow I need to architect it for many. I have the style function looping over the rules but only the last one is returned. The factory creates a style function but I don't know how to extend it with each read of a rule...

Comment: If you are familiar with how the filters work in OpenLayers 2, that's how I managed them.  Each filter string is converted into a filter object that has the `evaluate` method.  Inside the created style function, a feature gets evaluated with the created filters.  That's where the magic occurs.  I haven't got farther than the comparison filters (no logical yet).  See how it works in OpenLayers 2. That might help you a lot: http://dev.openlayers.org/releases/OpenLayers-2.13.1/doc/apidocs/files/OpenLayers/Filter/Comparison-js.html

Comment: I have done this successfully in OL2.x. I think what I am missing is how to the "filter" functions are added dynamically to the OL3.x style function. For example I think my factory needs to return: function( feature, resolution ) { filterFunction filterFunction filterFunction }. Is that correct? If so are you wrapping the filterFunctions in eval()? Are you adding them to the styleFunction as an array of eval()'s? Thanks very much for your assistance with this.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89294/discussion-between-alexandre-dube-and-morescratch).